# CHAR function on SQL Server is returning different values on different servers

Tags: sql-server

When I do

```
SELECT CHAR(193)
```

On my local database it returns `Á`, but when I do the same on a database running on another server it returns `┴`.

I expect `Á` as the correct value, how can I fix the function?

The databases were created individually, they aren't exactly the same.

Comment: What's the "default collation" on the two databases?  `SELECT name, collation_Name FROM sys.databases`

Comment: What are the database collations on each server? `Select SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`

Comment: Locally it is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, and the other is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI`

Comment: That's actually quite strange. I get `Á` for both these.

Comment: What font do you have set for management studio?: Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts And Colors, Grid Results (or Text Results). Are you using the same instance of Mgmt Studio to access both databases?

Comment: And just following on from Thomas's point - Do you get the same characters shown if you change to execute the query with "Results to text"?

Comment: `Microsoft Sans Serif`. Yes, I am using the same instance for both databases. I can see the character `Á` when I select for my local database, but on the remote it doesn't return `Á`.

Comment: As a curiosity, what happens if you call `Select Char(193) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` on the remote server? Do you get `Á`?

Comment: Character Map in Windows gives Á for "Windows: Western" and ┴ for "DOS: United States".  Hmm.

Comment: @Bruno - Yes I've reproduced here. Before I hadn't changed the collation of the database I was just relying on the `collate` clause. Now I see the results you are getting. The `collate` is obviously having some effect as the result changes but I wonder if it tries to convert it back.

Comment: @Thomas I get `-`. Wow @Will, good thinking! That never crossed my mind. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: In fact I've deleted my answer as I think it's entirely wrong and misleading. I now suspect that `CHAR(193)` returns `┴` then it does the conversion to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` afterwards which gives the `-`.

Comment: Do you think there is something I can do about that?

Comment: @Bruno - Try using NChar instead of Char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using NChar instead of Char:

```
SELECT NCHAR(193)
```

Answer (score 1):

The collation is not the same, run this to see that you get different answers

```
SELECT CHAR(193) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1256_CI_AS  
SELECT CHAR(193)
SELECT CHAR(193) Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

to find out the collation for the database run this

```
Select DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_name(),'Collation')
```